# Custom title in embeded pdf

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

when I embed pdf to html page, I want it to have custom title, not the name of the pdf document. And I can't access it with JS because of shadow DOM.

```
<embed src="pdfFiles/interfaces.pdf" width="600" height="500" alt="pdf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the DOM of a *user-agent* Shadow DOM, only custom Shadow DOM.

Maybe you can use an alternate way to embed a PDF (without the `<embed>` tag), like [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) from Mozilla.

See this SO question for further detail: [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)